# Performing Different custom segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have multiple view controllers and I want to perform a different custom segue when i transition to certain view controllers.

I've made the code correctly for the different custom segues and set the corresponding segues to that class.

My problem is, when i transition from **ViewControllerA** to **ViewControllerB** I want it to perform **CustomSegueA** & it does. When I transition from **ViewControllerB** to **ViewControllerC** I want it to perform **CustomSegueB** but it performs **CustomSegueA** instead. In fact, each subsequent transition will perform **CustomSegueA**. If I change the transition from **ViewControllerA** to **ViewControllerB** to **CustomSegueB** then each subsequent transition will use **CustomSegueB**.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How are you activating the Segues? Are you calling them in code or are they all hooked up in IB?

Comment: Programatically calls the segue when a certain method is called. not IB.. i found the problem though! it was a problem with the custom segue code....in the animation code

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in the custom segue code...for the animation I had

```
    - (void) perform {

UIViewController *sourceVC = (UIViewController *) self.sourceViewController;
UIViewController *destinationVC = (UIViewController *) self.destinationViewController;

[UIView transitionWithView:sourceVC.view duration:5.0
                   options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve
                animations:^{
                    [sourceVC.navigationController pushViewController:destinationVC animated:NO];
                }
                completion:NULL];
```

}

in the

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:sourceVC.view duration:5.0
```

i changed it to

```
    [UIView transitionWithView:sourceVC.navigationController.view duration:5.0
```

Don't know why that was the difference and only reason i was able to figure it out was by looking at some old projects i had when it worked